# How do you use storage service in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm trying to insert some storage data onto Bluemix, I searched many wiki pages but I couldn't come to conclude how to proceed. So can any one tell me how to store images, files in storage of Bluemix through any language code ( Java, Node.js)?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Just checking back in... Do one of the answers solve your problem? If not what issue are you hitting?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options at your disposal for storing files in your app. None of them include doing it in the app container file system as the file space is ephemeral and will be recreated from the droplet each time a new instance of your app is created.

You can use services like MongoLab, Cloudant, Object Storage, and Redis to store all kinda of blob data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using Bluemix to write a Cloud Foundry application, another option is `sshfs`. At your app's startup time, you can use sshfs to create a connection to a remote server that is mounted as a local directory. For example, you could create a `./data` directory that points to a remote SSH server and provides a persistent storage location for your app.

Here is [a blog post](http://blog.pivotal.io/cloud-foundry-pivotal/products/getting-started-with-wordpress-on-cloud-foundry) explaining how this strategy works and [a source repo](https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-ex-wordpress) showing it used to host a Wordpress blog in a Cloud Foundry app.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as others have suggested, there are a number of services for storing object data. Go to the Bluemix Catalog [1] and select "Data Management" in the left hand margin. Each of those services should have sufficient documentation to get you started, including many sample applications and tutorials. Just click on a service tile, and then click on the "View Docs" button to find the relevant documentation.

[1] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/cloudOEPaneId=store

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/ObjectStorageV2/index.html#gettingstarted.  The storage service in Bluemix is OpenStack Swift running in Softlayer.  Check out this page (http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/) for docs on Swift.

Here is a page that lists some clients for Swift.
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs

Answer (score 0):

As I search There was a service that name was Object Storage service and also was created by IBM. But, at the momenti I couldn't see it in the Bluemix Catalog. I guess , They gave it back and will publish new service in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that pobject store in bluemix is now S3 compatible.  So for instance you can use Boto or boto3 ( for python guys ) It will work 100% API comaptible. 
see some example here : https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-python.html

this script helps you to list recursively all objects in all buckets :

```
import boto3
endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint)
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        print("  - %s") % obj.key
```

If you want to specify your credentials this would be :

```
import boto3
endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint, aws_access_key_id=YouRACCessKeyGeneratedOnYouBlueMixDAShBoard, aws_secret_access_key=TheSecretKeyThatCOmesWithYourAccessKey, use_ssl=True)

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        print("  - %s") % obj.key
```

If you want to create a "hello.txt" file in a new bucket. :

```
import boto3
endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint, aws_access_key_id=YouRACCessKeyGeneratedOnYouBlueMixDAShBoard, aws_secret_access_key=TheSecretKeyThatCOmesWithYourAccessKey, use_ssl=True)
my_bucket=s3.create_bucket('my-new-bucket')
s3.Object(my_bucket, 'hello.txt').put(Body=b"I'm a test file")
```

If you want to upload a file in a new bucket :

```
import boto3
endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint, aws_access_key_id=YouRACCessKeyGeneratedOnYouBlueMixDAShBoard, aws_secret_access_key=TheSecretKeyThatCOmesWithYourAccessKey, use_ssl=True)
my_bucket=s3.create_bucket('my-new-bucket')
timestampstr = str (timestamp)
s3.Bucket(my_bucket).upload_file(<location of yourfile>,<your file name>, ExtraArgs={ "ACL": "public-read", "Metadata": {"METADATA1": "resultat" ,"METADATA2": "1000","gid": "blabala000", "timestamp": timestampstr },},)
```